# How to delete the auto-generate first line in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I am wondering is there a graceful way in C# to delete the first line in RichTextBox,

I am using RichTextBox to create a chat room, I would like to show the Date or Image by clicking a button , so here I go

```
Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
para.Inlines.Add( DateTime.Now.ToString());
//para.Inlines.Add( Image);
rt.Document.Blocks.Add(para);
```

rt is the name of RichTextBox,
but the item shows in the RichTextBox in a new row , so everytime I need to type Delete to see the Date/Image, so is there a way to delete the first line systematically ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
rt.Document.Blocks.Remove(rt.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
myRichTextBox.Select(0, myRichTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(1));
myRichTextBox.SelectedText = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove first line from Paragraph?

```
para.Inlines.Remove(para.Inlines.FirstOrDefault());
```